Подскажите, почему при выполнение задачи(Среднее геометрическое элементов за минимальным элементом) в ответе добавляет в массив единицу?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<math.h>
#define NMAX 100

int main()
{
    int imin, min, n, i;
    int x[NMAX];
    int sumNegatives = 0;
    double sum;
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    // Задаем массив
    do
    {
        printf("Введите размер массива от 1 до %d = ", NMAX);
        scanf_s("%d", &n);

        if (n <= 0 || n > NMAX)
        {
            printf("Размер массива n = %d, не соответствует размеру 1..%d элементов\n", n, NMAX);
            printf("Для завершения программы нажмите любую клавишу\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (n < 1 || n > NMAX);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%3d  ]=", i);
        scanf_s("%d", &x[i]);
    }
    // Вывод исходного массива
    printf("Исходный массив х размером %d\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%8.2d", x[i]);

    imin = 0;

    // Определение минимального элемента и его позиции
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < x[imin])
            imin = i;
    }
    min = x[imin];
    sum = 1.0;
    // Определение среднего геометрического за минимальным элементом
    for (i = imin + 1; i < n; i++)
        sum *= x[i];
    sum = pow(sum, 1.0 / n);
    
    printf("\n\nМинимальный элемент массива: %d\n", min);
    printf("Позиция минимального элемента: %d\n", imin);
    printf("Среднее арифметическое за минимальным элементом: %.2f\n", sum);
    printf("\n\nДля завершения программы нажмите любую клавишу\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


И что вам мешает это сделать?  Будьте конкретнее.

Не совсем понимаю как это сделать арифметическое знаю, а геометрическую, втыку не дам

Google уже не работает? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5

Да гугл хорошая вещь, я говорю, что в программе, не вдупляю как оно будет выглядеть, вот даже на примере арифметического
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
if (x[i] < 0)
sumNegatives += x[i];
}

Задать начальное значение 1 и умножать вместо суммирования
